# Gatsby project .cache folder size issue

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

while generating Gatsby build locally and in production, my project generated .cache folder with a 4.48 GB size. mainly from `.cache/webpack/stage-build-html` and `/stage-build-javascript` both are getting big sizes these both folders contain `0.pack`, `1.pack` type of files which are big in size.

how can I reduce the .cache folder size? generally, in my project, there are lots of MDX files with huge MDX data and also contain HTML tables in MDX files (tables are pretty big)

dependencies used in project -

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@docsearch/css": "^3.5.1",
    "@docsearch/react": "^3.5.1",
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^2.1.3",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/dompurify": "^3.0.2",
    "@xstyled/styled-components": "^3.6.0",
    "ariakit": "^2.0.0-next.41",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "2.0.2",
    "babel-preset-gatsby": "^2.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "dompurify": "^3.0.2",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-catch-links": "^4.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-compile-es6-packages": "^2.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^4.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-mdx": "^4.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect": "^1.1.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "1.7.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^5.6.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^5.6.0",
    "gatsby-remark-autolink-headers": "^5.19.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^6.6.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.6.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.6.0",
    "github-slugger": "^1.4.0",
    "polished": "^4.1.4",
    "prism-react-renderer": "^1.2.1",
    "prismjs": "^1.26.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-live": "^2.4.1",
    "remark-gfm": "^1.0.0",
    "remark-html": "^15.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
    "unist-util-visit": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/mdx2-csf": "^1.0.0",
    "conventional-github-releaser": "^3.1.5",
    "gatsby": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "standard-version": "^9.3.2"
  }
```